# checking if SQL query was excuted in PDO

Tags: php, pdo

in mysql_query we can check if the query was executed or not by doing this:

```
$query = $yourdbconnection->fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_name"));
if ($query){ // query is working }
else { // query is not working }
```

in PDO, I am doing something like this:

```
$query = $yourdbconnection->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_name");
$fetchquery = $query->fetchAll();
if ($fetchquery) { // query is working}
else { // query not working}
```

Is my code effective? what exactly the `if` statement doing? Is it doing the same thing that `mysql_query` was doing? How can I check if the query is returning 0 rows or not?

**[EDIT]**

I have found those solutions as a workaround to the problem

1. using `$stmt->fetch()`

   prepare($sql);
       $stmt->execute();

   ```
   if ($data = $stmt->fetch()) {
       do {
           echo $data['model'] . '<br>';
       } while ($data = $stmt->fetch());
   } else {
       echo 'Empty Query';}
   ```

   ?>
2. adding another query to count the number of rows see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15325834/890669)

However, I am still looking for better solutions

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see if your query was executed, I would suggest setting your PDO in exception mode like Your Common Sense suggested. You can do it like this:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'user', 'pass');
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Concerning the best way to check if a query returned values or not in PDO, I suggest just doing a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table` query, like this:

```
<?php
$query = $dbh->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table');
if ($query->fetchColumn() != 0) {
    /* Query has result(s) */
    $query = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM table');
    /* ... */
} else {
    /* Query has no results */
}
?>
```

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: [rowCount()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) is not a portable way to check for the number of results with SELECT queries.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't notice that. Guess I learned something. I would then suggest doing a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table` query and then executing your normal query if the count is > 0. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score -1):

there are 2 questions in your post.

> 1) what is the best way to check if the query returned values or not in PDO?

check returned values

> 2) how to check if SQL query was excuted in PDO

set PDO in exception mode as described in the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

By the way, for the `"SELECT * FROM tbl_name"` query you may wish to use `fetchAll()` instead of `fetch()`.

Comment: "does my code do the job?"

Comment: does your code do the job?

Comment: I do not know, you tell me!