# PDO insert if statement

Tags: php, pdo

I would like to know how to check if the insert statement is executed or not.

my current code of checking it is this:

```
$query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO editlog VALUES('',:whoadd,:doing,NOW())");
$query-> execute(array(':whoadd'   => $whoadd,':doing'   => $doing));
if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {
// insert statement have been executed 
}
else 
{
// something went wrong
}
```

is there a better way than using `$query->rowCount() > 0` ? I have heard that `rowCount()` itself runs a query to mysql database..so, what is a good alternative?

Comment: First, you has been [asking this question 2 times already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325487/checking-if-sql-query-was-excuted-in-pdo) Next, [you are still confusing 2 matters - if query was executed at all or if it returned any rows.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15325557/285587) **Please do finally understand the difference.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mark Parnell suggested, wrapping the `execute` call in an `if` statement does the trick. It might prove useful later on to set some attributes of your database object, too:

```
 $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Causing PDO to throw exceptions (`PDOException`) in case a query fails. You can set these attributes by passing an array as fourth parameter to the constructor:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=foobar;host=127.0.0.1','your','pass',
                      array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ'));
```

For example, [here's a full list of all attributes that can be specified](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php).

Answer (score 1):

Check the return value of the `execute` call:

```
if ($query->execute(array(':whoadd' => $whoadd,':doing' => $doing))) {
    // insert statment have been excuted 
}
else 
{
    // something went wrong
}
```

Comment: does that work only on insert statment? or can it be applied to select, delete, and update statments?

Comment: It will work on any statement, though it will simply tell you whether it executed successfully. E.g. it won't tell you if any rows were actually updated by an `UPDATE` query.

Comment: to check if it was actually updated, I need to use `$query->rowCount() > 0` right? what else can I use?

Comment: Yes. For an `INSERT` query just checking the success of the `execute` method is sufficient (if it was successful, you know it was inserted), but if you want to know that something was actually changed when doing an `UPDATE` you need to check `rowCount()`.

Comment: It's wrong answer. This ancient way of dealing with queries shouldn't be used with PDO

Comment: @MarkParnell: An update query that doesn't update any rows can be a successful query nonetheless: `UPDATE foobar SET foo = 'bar' WHERE alwaysfalse = TRUE;`, just because no rows are eligible, doesn't mean the query failed. Just set the PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE to PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION and let PDO throw in case something went wrong

Answer (score 0):

PDOStatement::execute() itself will return true on success or false on failure.